# How to take sum of column with join from relationship table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to get sum of column income in table charges. that charges table has `belongsTo` Relation with Consignment and consignment has `hasMany` relation with Charges. Now the case is I am trying take  sum of income column where `invoice_id` is 63.

Here is my effort.

```
Consignment::where('invoice_id', 63)->join('charges', 'charges.object_id', '=', 'consignments.id')
            ->where('charges.model', '=', 'Consignment')
            ->groupBy('consignments.id')
            ->get(['consignments.id', DB::raw('sum(charges.income) as income')])
            ->sum('income');
```

I don't know whats wrong with it.

Comment: Can you write a raw query that does what you want?

Comment: `select sum(income) from charges inner join  consignment consignments.id == charges.id  where invoice_id == 63 where model == 'Consignment' ` sorry if I am doing wrong in syntax

Comment: did you resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the relation is easier. Try this:

```php
$sum = Charge::query()->whereHas('consignment', function ($query) {
    $query->where('invoice_id', 63);
})->sum('income');
```

Comment: if there are 100000 consignments where has query will take long time

Comment: @Bilalarshad no, it's a query builder statement, it's no different than a join in the query. actualy it is a join. same goes for the `sum()` method, here it is in the query builder, so it's like doing  `DB::raw('sum(charges.income)')`

Comment: @Bilalarshad it's equivalent word for word to what you wrote in the comment section of your question. You can check that by switching `sum('income')` with `select(DB::raw('sum(charges.income)'))->toSql()` and check the query that's gonna be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query result in $result and use.

```
collect($result)->pluck('income')->sum()
```